# Convert hex string to int32 with 0x (C#)

Tags: c#, string, integer, hex, converters

I have a string that gets "0030FF". I wanted to convert it to int32 by adding a 0x at the beginning. Is there any way?

The int needs to be like this: 0x0030FF.

Comment: `int result = Convert.ToInt32(myString, 16);` you don't have to add `"0x"` but you can do it

Comment: @DmitryBychenko there is no way to add 0x at the beginning? I need it to be equal to string, but this form is also useful.

Comment: `int` just holds an *integer value*, like `123`, it doesn't have any *format*. If you want to *represent* `int` you can use formatting: `Console.Write($"0x{myInt:X6}");`

Comment: As said by others, an `int` type represents signed integers numbers like -1 and 10. You can't and don't need to "*add*" **0x** at the beginning of the int. You only can add that in a hex string representation of the integer, as well as a binary like 010101b. Thus the question is non-sense, unless you ask how to add **0x** add before the string: `string strHex = "0030FF"; string strHexCorrected = "0x" + strHex;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
string value = "0030FF";
int result = int.Parse(value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
string numberedHex = $"0x{result:X6}";
```

Comment: Is it possible to add 0x to the beginning of this int? I want it to return 0x0030ff

Comment: @LawLuki Now I understand what you want... Note, int cannot represent a value that is not a number, if you want it to look 0x0030FF you need to use a string. I updated my answer.

Comment: A.k.a. [`"0x" + "0030FF"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68605716/convert-hex-string-to-int32-with-0x-c#comment121248092_68605716)...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *convert* given string into an `int`, you can use `Convert`:

```
 // 16 - we expect myString being a hexadecimal int representation 
 int myInt = Convert.ToInt32(myString, 16);
```

If you then want to represent `myInt` as `0x...` you can use *formatting* (note, that `int myInt` is just some integer value, say, `123` and doesn't have any format):

```
 // X6 is a formatting string: we want at least 6 hexadecimal digits 
 string myHex = $"0x{myInt:X6}";

 Console.Write(myHex);
```